# Change email for update notification

Tags: automatic-updates

I've recently got the email with the update notification.

`[Example.com] Your site has updated to WordPress 3.8.1`

`Howdy! Your site at http://www.example.com has been updated automatically to WordPress 3.8.1. [...]`

**I want to change the email where this notification goes.** I seems that it's not connected with any user.

I've searched all the backend and I can't seem to find the required setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setting you are looking for is found in "Settings"=>"General"=>"E-Mail Adress".

All the Emails WordPress or Plugins send out are sent to the `admin_mail`, which is returned by `get_option( 'admin_mail' )`, and this Emailadress is not always connected to a user.

If you first install WordPress, the first user created gets the role `administrator`, and the same Emailadress is used for this setting, but can be changed afterwards.

This actually makes a lot of sense, as a site could have a few administrators (or none, to be picky). Not everybody needs to get this information, as well as someone *should* get it, even if a site does not have an administrator registered in the database.

This is the reason for the two distinctive fields/settings.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to check out this plugin which allows you to change where the email goes:

[background-update-notification-email-address](http://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/background-update-notification-email-address)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `auto_core_update_email` filter to change the default admin email.

```
add_filter( 'auto_core_update_email', function($email){
  $email['to'] = 'updateWP@example.com'; // Override email address
  return $email;  
});
```